Shafi’i: Can a bride give consent alongside wali?
If a wali is present to consent to a shafi’i nikah alongside the groom is it permissible for the bride to also give public verbal consent as part of the ceremony?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
